# VS2010 C# WPF web-browser control opens ppt/pptx outside the application

Tags: c#, wpf, powerpoint

Hi All,

I am creating a small application using C# WPF. This application  have to open PDF, PPT inside the WPF form. I have used web-browser control to open pdf, it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to open the ppt/pptx file using the web-browser control, it gives me a download  pop-up & opens the ppt outside the application.

I am not able to figure out the issue. 
Is there a right way to open the ppt/pptx using the web-browser control or we need to use any other control?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Vijay Kumbhar

Comment: Do you get different results from PPTX files than from PPT files?

Comment: No it is the same result :(

Comment: Does it happen the same if you try with regular IE?

Comment: Yes, if i try this with regular IE, the same thing happens :(

Comment: If it happens with PPTX files but not PPTs, it's likely due to the browser, absent the needed correct MIME settings for PPTX, is sniffing the file, finding that it's actually a zip, so offering to download it.  There's a security setting that disables this behavior.  Something to do with MIME sniffing or detection, I think.

Comment: Maybe your IE is configured to automatically download PPT/PPTX files?